# Display presentmodelviewcontroller on tabbar

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

How to display modelviewcontroller on tabbar with navigation controller?
I try to find solution on SO, but i didn't get related answer, please help me.

Comment: @Bartek, i want to show modelviewcontroller on one selected tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created customview with navigation bar and back button and added to my maintabbarcontroller.

It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for following up on your question. I think it might be a bit localized, however .. but it will remain for a while should other people encounter the same.